# Installing sshd on an existing BusyBox installation?

Tags: ssh, busybox

Is it possible to install `sshd` on a running BusyBox-based router?

Comment: This could be a business environment question. It doesn't say it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the toolchain for that router, you can statically compile [Dropbear](https://github.com/mkj/dropbear).  That would be best for this situation since, based on the fact that it uses Busybox, resources are already strained.